# Security Exception WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY in Samsung phones

Tags: android, permissions, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am developing an app using the Motion Samsung library. one of the requirements is to require permissions as follows in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name= "com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
```

However on some phones (and just some phones) using the release APK from the store, I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY permission is required.
```

which does not seem to make much sense as I have asked for the permission. 
I suppose this must not be down to obfuscation during proguard (otherwise it would not work for any phone I guess)? 
Is it a way to tell me that the specific phone does not support the library somehow?

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new SamsungPass library v 1.2.2 fixes the problem.
You can download the new library here:
http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass/releases

Comment: is  SamsungPass library required to use Motion SDK?